# Step up dynamo voltage with transformer

Tags: power, transformer, dc-dc-converter, boost, dynamo

I'm using a 100 turn coil and some magnets to create a 100 mV AC signal from my bike wheel. I need to boost that voltage up to at least 400 mV to use a DC-DC boost converter to get 5 V. For that reason, I'm trying to use a 1:5 transformer to boost the voltage a bit before the DC-DC.

- When I measure the voltage of the "dynamo" with my oscilloscope, I
  turned around 100 mV (no load or 20 Ω load)
- But at the output of the transformer I always read 0 V

What am I doing wrong?
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146411/discussion-on-question-by-nasib-fahim-step-up-dynamo-voltage-with-transformer); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

To summarise the feedback in the comments and add some more:

1. 100 turns is not enough.
2. A DC-DC converter is unlikely to work with a 400 mV input (but you may have found one designed for energy harvesting which might) but bear in mind that for a 1:10 step up in voltage you will need ten times the current on the low-voltage side than you draw on the high-voltage side.
3. You are using an SMPS ferrite transformer designed for 100+ kHz. At 25 kph your will be running at about 200 RPM. With six magnets that will give you 1200 pulses per minute or 20 Hz. That's 1/5000 the design frequency of the transformer. That's not going to work. You would have some hope if you used a mains frequency transformer.
4. "*i use single pole magnets on the wheel*". No, except in weird particle physics all magnets have two poles - a north and a south.

[image]

5. You appear to be using door latch magnets. The centre forms one pole and the outer case forms the other. When used as a door latch the keeper closes the magnetic circuit and gives the "6 kg" rating. With any air gap the force of attraction will fall very rapidly. Because both the north and south poles of your magnets are facing the coil nearly all the flux will go directly across the gap between the poles and hardly any through your coil. Effectively, the north and south poles cancel out.

I recommend that you forget this design and study home-made wind-turbine designs using rare-earth magnets. Pay attention to the design of the magnetic circuits and spend some time (many hours) studying magnetics to gain some understanding if you are going to deviate from a proven design.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your repply!

Let me clarify these points. 

1. I will try to reduce the gap and to make more turns. Now with 200 i get arund 0.4V 
2. I am using TPS61202DSCR to get 5V from around 0.4-1V . But my main purpose is to increase the number of turns to avoid high current on the output of the coil. 
3. If you take a look at the picture provided i got a period of 0.07s what means around 14Hz you are right 
4. I mean single pole on the same face. 
5. I will try to increase the magnets strengh and to reduce the air gap. 

Thank you so much for your info!

Comment: One last question: 

Which points do you recommend me to pay attention when i design the main coil ( diammeter of the wire, number of turns , area...) ? 

Thanks a lot

Comment: 4. As explained, those magnets have both poles on the same face. Am I correct that they are door latch magnets? As suggested, review some wind turbine designs to get specifications. I don't have any.